# Unnecessary Hash Match in Query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, index-tuning, azure-sql-database, entity-framework

I've just migrated a database from SQLExpress (Entity, Database First) to Azure (Entity, Code First) and some of the indexes are missing because they werent migrated (on purpose, I think a lot of them are unneeded).

I have a stored procedure that I've run on both servers and the old one runs in about 4 seconds but it takes about 36 seconds on Azure. The indexes for the tables in question seem to be identical but on Azure, the execution plan includes a costly Hash Match which seems completely unnecessary to me. Why would this Hash Match be included?

The Function mentioned in the query is defined as follows (it's the same on both servers)

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_get_group_children] (@GroupID INT)
RETURNS @Results TABLE (GroupID INT, GroupName VARCHAR(MAX), UsersInGroup INT)
AS BEGIN

    --DECLARE @GroupID INT = 905
    DECLARE @ChildGroups TABLE (GroupID INT, ParentGroup INT, Name VARCHAR(100));

    WITH ChildGroups (GroupID, ParentGroup, Name) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            GroupID, ParentGroup, Name
        FROM 
            dbo.[Group]
        WHERE 
            ParentGroup = @GroupID OR
            GroupID = @GroupID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            g2.GroupID, g2.ParentGroup, g2.Name
        FROM 
            dbo.[Group] g2 
        INNER JOIN 
            ChildGroups 
        ON 
            ChildGroups.GroupID = g2.ParentGroup
    )

    INSERT INTO @ChildGroups (GroupID, ParentGroup, Name)
    SELECT DISTINCT GroupID, ParentGroup, Name
    FROM ChildGroups;

    INSERT INTO @Results (GroupID, GroupName, UsersInGroup)
    SELECT C.GroupID, 
            C.Name, 
            UserCount = (SELECT COUNT(UserCompanyID) FROM UserCompany WHERE GroupID = C.GroupID)
    FROM @ChildGroups C

    RETURN

END;
```

The XML for the [old server](http://www.hastebin.com/bocewoduxi.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.4000.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="14" StatementEstRows="51.9393" StatementId="3" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="6.75694" StatementText="SELECT COUNT(*) TheCount,&#xA;             DateStamp&#xA;       FROM (&#xA;         SELECT LE.UserID,&#xA;                 CONVERT(DATE, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, le.DateStamp), 0)), 103) DateStamp&#xA;         FROM LogEventPageView LPV&#xA;          INNER JOIN LogEntry LE ON LE.LogEntryID = LPV.LogEntryID&#xA;           INNER JOIN UserCompany UC ON UC.UserID = LE.UserID&#xA;         WHERE LE.CompanyID = @CompanyID&#xA;            AND UC.GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM fn_get_group_children(@GroupID))&#xA;            GROUP BY &#xA;              CONVERT(DATE, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, le.DateStamp), 0)), 103),&#xA;             LE.UserID&#xA;      ) As LE&#xA;        GROUP BY DateStamp&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xC4E6BF6DFC5D78CD" QueryPlanHash="0x19BC421DCA586E66">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" MemoryGrant="1776" CachedPlanSize="64" CompileTime="98" CompileCPU="98" CompileMemory="2752">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="5.29393E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="51.9393" LogicalOp="Sequence" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sequence" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="6.75694">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="19" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Sequence>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="1.157E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Table-valued function" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table-valued function" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.157E-06">
                  <OutputList />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TableValuedFunction>
                    <DefinedValues />
                    <Object Database="[Taploma]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fn_get_group_children]" />
                    <ParameterList>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@GroupID]">
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Column="@GroupID" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </ParameterList>
                  </TableValuedFunction>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="0.00164458" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="51.9393" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="6.75688">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <ComputeScalar>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1014],0)">
                          <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Convert>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="0.00164458" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="51.9393" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="6.75688">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="19" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <StreamAggregate>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
                              <Aggregate AggType="countstar" Distinct="false" />
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <GroupBy>
                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                        </GroupBy> 
                            ...see the rest in original link
```

The XML for the [new server](http://www.hastebin.com/etupodorip.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.5" Build="13.0.1700.1350" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="14" StatementEstRows="3951.48" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="130" StatementSubTreeCost="0.394625" StatementText="SELECT COUNT(*) TheCount,&#xD;&#xA;               DateStamp&#xD;&#xA;      FROM (&#xD;&#xA;            SELECT LE.UserID,&#xD;&#xA;                CONVERT(DATE, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, le.DateStamp), 0)), 103) DateStamp&#xD;&#xA;            FROM LogEventPageView LPV&#xD;&#xA;         INNER JOIN LogEntry LE ON LE.LogEntryID = LPV.LogEntryID&#xD;&#xA;          INNER JOIN UserCompany UC ON UC.UserID = LE.UserID&#xD;&#xA;            WHERE LE.CompanyID = @CompanyID&#xD;&#xA;           AND UC.GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM fn_get_group_children(@GroupID))&#xD;&#xA;           GROUP BY &#xD;&#xA;             CONVERT(DATE, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, le.DateStamp), 0)), 103),&#xD;&#xA;                LE.UserID&#xD;&#xA;     ) As LE&#xD;&#xA;       GROUP BY DateStamp" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x5BC82C3318247D4A" QueryPlanHash="0x4CF18E5046FF47AE" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSqlHandle="0x0900189ECDF81062A1124BF15DB86CAB85AE0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" DatabaseContextSettingsId="7" ParentObjectId="386100416" StatementParameterizationType="0" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="EstimatedDOPIsOne" MemoryGrant="2136" CachedPlanSize="80" CompileTime="24" CompileCPU="24" CompileMemory="1600">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="2048" SerialDesiredMemory="2136" RequiredMemory="2048" DesiredMemory="2136" RequestedMemory="2136" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="2136" MaxUsedMemory="1536" MaxQueryMemory="552560" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="17616030" EstimatedPagesCached="1101001" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" MaxCompileMemory="2301136" />
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="3608" ElapsedTime="37613" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="0.00405148" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="3951.48" LogicalOp="Sequence" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sequence" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.394625">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="19" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="37611" ActualCPUms="3607" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Sequence>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="0.000100157" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Table-valued function" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table-valued function" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.000100157">
                  <OutputList />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="31" ActualCPUms="30" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TableValuedFunction>
                    <DefinedValues />
                    <Object Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fn_get_group_children]" Storage="RowStore" />
                    <ParameterList>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@GroupID]">
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Column="@GroupID" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </ParameterList>
                  </TableValuedFunction>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="0" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="3951.48" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.390474">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <ComputeScalar>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1012],0)">
                          <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1012" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Convert>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="0.0142006" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="3951.48" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.390474">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1012" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="19" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="37580" ActualCPUms="3577" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <StreamAggregate>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1012" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
                              <Aggregate AggType="countstar" Distinct="false" />
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <GroupBy>
                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                        </GroupBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="10" EstimateCPU="0.00012835" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="20374.8" LogicalOp="Distinct Sort" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.376273">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <Warnings>
                            <SpillToTempDb SpillLevel="2" SpilledThreadCount="1" />
                            <SortSpillDetails GrantedMemoryKb="568" UsedMemoryKb="568" WritesToTempDb="322" ReadsFromTempDb="322" />
                          </Warnings>
                          <MemoryFractions Input="0.666667" Output="1" />
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="5430" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="37579" ActualCPUms="3576" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="322" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" InputMemoryGrant="568" OutputMemoryGrant="216" UsedMemoryGrant="568" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <Sort Distinct="true">
                            <OrderBy>
                              <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                              </OrderByColumn>
                              <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                                <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="UserID" />
                              </OrderByColumn>
                            </OrderBy>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="14" EstimateCPU="4.18E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="6.6469" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.364884">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="UserID" />
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="322376" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="35095" ActualCPUms="3252" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                                <OuterReferences>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="LogEntryID" />
                                </OuterReferences>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="18" EstimateCPU="0.115962" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="10" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.335142">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="LogEntryID" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="UserID" />
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <Warnings>
                                    <SpillToTempDb SpillLevel="3" SpilledThreadCount="1" />
                                    <HashSpillDetails GrantedMemoryKb="1024" UsedMemoryKb="968" WritesToTempDb="5600" ReadsFromTempDb="5600" />
                                  </Warnings>
                                  <MemoryFractions Input="0.181818" Output="0.333333" />
                                  <RunTimeInformation>
                                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="673440" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="29509" ActualCPUms="1506" ActualScans="68" ActualLogicalReads="4168" ActualPhysicalReads="564" ActualReadAheads="5600" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" InputMemoryGrant="1040" OutputMemoryGrant="1048" UsedMemoryGrant="968" />
                                  </RunTimeInformation>
                                  <Hash>
                                    <DefinedValues>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="UserID" />
                                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([SalesAcademyDev].[dbo].[LogEntry].[UserID] as [LE].[UserID])">
                                          <Aggregate AggType="ANY" Distinct="false">
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Identifier>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="UserID" />
                                              </Identifier>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </Aggregate>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                    </DefinedValues>
                                    <HashKeysBuild>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="LogEntryID" />
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                                    </HashKeysBuild>
                                    <BuildResidual>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[SalesAcademyDev].[dbo].[LogEntry].[LogEntryID] as [LE].[LogEntryID] = [SalesAcademyDev].[dbo].[LogEntry].[LogEntryID] as [LE].[LogEntryID] AND [Expr1005] = [Expr1005]">
                                        <Logical Operation="AND">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="LogEntryID" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="LogEntryID" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Compare>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Compare>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Logical>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </BuildResidual>
                                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="18" EstimateCPU="0.0020998" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="14992.3" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="7" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.21918">
                                      <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="LogEntryID" />
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="UserID" />
                                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                                      </OutputList>
                                      <ComputeScalar>
                                        <DefinedValues>
                                          <DefinedValue>
                                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT(date,dateadd(month,datediff(month,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',[SalesAcademyDev].[dbo].[LogEntry].[DateStamp] as [LE].[DateStamp]),'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'),103)">
                                              <Convert DataType="date" Style="103" Implicit="false">
                                                <ScalarOperator>
                                                  <Intrinsic FunctionName="dateadd">
                                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                                      <Const ConstValue="(2)" />
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                                      <Intrinsic FunctionName="datediff">
                                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                                          <Const ConstValue="(2)" />
                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                                          <Const ConstValue="'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'" />
                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                                          <Identifier>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[SalesAcademyDev]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[LogEntry]" Alias="[LE]" Column="DateStamp" />
                                                          </Identifier>
                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                      </Intrinsic>
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                                      <Const ConstValue="'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'" />
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                  </Intrinsic>
                                                </ScalarOperator>
                                              </Convert>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </DefinedValue>
                                        </DefinedValues>
                                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.0877716" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="20998" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.21708">

...see the rest in original link
```

Comment: You may find it a bit easier to paste plans here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that the hash match is a problem is because the row estimates are incorrect. Your function `fn_get_group_children()` is probably contributing to this problem. Azure is estimating that the function will return 100 rows but it actually returns 203, and this contributes to poor row estimates for the rest of the plan.

When the row estimates are way too small, not enough RAM is allocated for sorts and hash matches and in your plan both the sort and the hash match spill to `tempdb` and all that writing to disk takes a long time.

If possible, try rewriting `fn_get_group_children()` as a subquery for this query and see if that improves performance. I believe that your query could be expressed without multi-statement, table-valued functions thusly:

```
With ChildGroups As (
    Select GroupID, GroupID As ParentGroupID
      From [Group]
    Union All
    Select g.GroupID, c.ParentGroupID
      From [Group] As g
      Join ChildGroups As c On c.GroupID = g.ParentGroupID)
SELECT COUNT(*) TheCount, DateStamp
  FROM (
    SELECT LE.UserID,
        CONVERT(DATE, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, le.DateStamp), 0)), 103) DateStamp
      FROM LogEventPageView LPV
      INNER JOIN LogEntry LE ON LE.LogEntryID = LPV.LogEntryID
      INNER JOIN UserCompany UC ON UC.UserID = LE.UserID
      WHERE LE.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND UC.GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM ChildGroups Where ParentGroupID = @GroupID)
      GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, le.DateStamp), 0)), 103), LE.UserID) As LE
  GROUP BY DateStamp;
```

The estimate for rows from the function on the old server is 1, many of the other estimates are different too (2012 introduced a new estimator). Because it has different estimates, it chooses a different plan, and it so happens that the plan performs better.